# Listbox list scroll not showing last item

Tags: excel, vba, user-interface, scroll, listbox

I have A listbox.list which is opening on keypress enter in textbox
I have the same problem like here: [How to fix an Excel listbox that can't scroll the last element into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859459/how-to-fix-an-excel-listbox-that-cant-scroll-the-last-element-into-view).

This do trick for me but only on first listbox.list occur, if I press enter second time this trick do not work. When I go to rand cell and when go to textbox again trick works on first listbox appear but on second doesn

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to adjust columns width to not have horizontal scroll bar